# Sort 2-d array using arsort

Tags: php, arrays

Here is my array `prob` with two values `value` (int) and `tag` (string).

At the end of loop I want to sort array by `value` and want to print top 5 values with their `tag`.

```
        foreach($POS as $p)
        {
            //echo "POS  :".$p."<br/>";
            while ($row1 = @mysqli_fetch_array($selectTag))
            {
                //Calculate total pos for given tag
                //echo "Tag : ".$row1['tag']."<br/>";
                $selectPOS1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from koove_posts where tag = '".$row1['tag']."'");
                while ($row2 = @mysqli_fetch_array($selectPOS1))
                {
                    //echo $row2['pos']."<br/>";
                    $totalPOSs.=$row2['pos'].",";       
                }
                $totalPOS_count = str_word_count($totalPOSs);

                //calculate how many times particular 'pos' appears for given tag
                $pos_Count = substr_count($totalPOSs, $p);

                //Calculate the probability for each part of speach
                $prob[] = (object) array(
                    "value" => ($pos_Count + 1)/ ($totalPOS_count + $distinct_pos_Count),
                    "tag"   => $row1['tag'],
                    );
                    }               
        }

        arsort($prob);
        $prob = array_slice($prob, 0, 5);
        foreach ($prob as $array)
        {
            echo "Tag :". $array->tag." Probablity :".$array->value."<br/>";
        }
```

I tried this, but it prints first 5 tags from list.

Comment: `arsort` doesn't work on 2-d arrays. You need to use `uksort` so you can provide a comparison function that tests the appropriate keys.

Comment: @Barmar: thanks dude, any further help for this scenario?

Comment: I held out hope that you could figure out the rest on your own, you just needed a nudge in the right direction. Once again, my hopes were dashed.

Comment: @Barmar: sorry dude. next time I will surely take care and give a try on my own

Comment: @Barmar: here i tried with uksort, what should be the value of 2nd parameter?? http://ideone.com/o6zG7n

Comment: It should be uasort, like in Marcin's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `uasort` function this way:

```
<?php

$prob = [];

$prob[] = (object) array('value' => 1, 'tag' => 2);
$prob[] = (object) array('value' => 2, 'tag' => 4);
$prob[] = (object) array('value' => 3, 'tag' => 6);
$prob[] = (object) array('value' => 4, 'tag' => 8);
$prob[] = (object) array('value' => 5, 'tag' => 10);
$prob[] = (object) array('value' => 6, 'tag' => 12);

var_dump($prob);


uasort ($prob, function($a, $b) {

if ($a->value == $b->value) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a->value < $b->value) ? 1 : -1;    

});


var_dump($prob);
```

Comment: thanks, I check your example independently, which worked. But when I tried it in my code it gave `Undefined property: stdClass::$value` error in `if` and `return`

Comment: @cyclic Have you put `uasort` from my code instead of `arsort($prob);`? If so you need to check if all `$prob` have defined both value and tag. Maybe before your loop `$prob` array is not empty?